# Prevent ARP spoofing in AP, “wl deauthenticate” command

Tags: linux, networking, shell, dd-wrt, arp

I am in a situation where I cannot do MAC filtering in an AP and I need to block a user that is ARP spoofing the network. I am trying to use the command `wl deauthenticate` to kick the client. And I want to do it repeatedly.

```
while true; do
wl deauthenticate <mac>
sleep 1
done
```

But when I start this command, the access point stops accepting wireless connections and gets blocked until I disable the command or restart the AP. Any suggestions so I can execute the command repeatedly without stopping the wireless? Can I use iptables to drop the ARP spoof packets? Or is it as I think, that the ARP spoofing can't be blocked by iptables because the ARP protocol is lower than IP in the network stack?